# display Streamed Response in a twig template symfony 3

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I have a controller which is returning a streamed response.
The method works fine, but displays my result in a blank page.

```
$response = new StreamedResponse();
  //$cmd='ping -c 5 www.google.fr';
  $process = new Process($cmd);
  $process->setWorkingDirectory($move_to_project);
  $process->setTimeout(60000000000000);
  $response->setCallback(function() use ($process) {
        $process->run(function ($type, $buffer) {
            if (Process::ERR === $type) {
                echo 'ERR > '.$buffer;
            } else {
                echo $buffer;
                ob_flush();
                flush();
                echo '<br>';
            }
        });
    });


    $response->setStatusCode(200);
    return $response;
```

I want to send the response to a twig template. 
I tried this

```
return $this->render('AKTestBundle:Test:specific.html.twig', array('res' => $response));
```

but it just posts the header of the response.

Comment: It does not make any sense to try to wrap this in a `twig` template. Conside this, you create a twig template which holds an iframe. In that iframe you place the URI towards your script with the streamed response in it

Comment: you mean like this ?  <iframe>
{{ render(controller('AKTestBundle:Test:exe')) }}</iframe>
</div>

Comment: No place the script you made above in a seperate script e.g. `process.php` then do `<iframe src="http://www.example.com/process.php"></iframe>`

Comment: it's working fiiine :D :D u saved my life ^_^